# Change Age on Facebook

Tags: facebook, profile

When I try to change my birthday on Facebook, it won't let me. How can I change it so that my correct age is displayed?

Comment: Have you tried the steps that the answer below has outlined already?  If not, please elaborate on "won't let me."

Answer (score 3):

[How do I edit my birthday?](https://www.facebook.com/help/121641674584595/)

> To edit your date of birth:
>
> 1. Go to your timeline
> 2. Click the Update Info button (under your cover photo)
> 3. Find the Basic Info section and click Edit
> 4. Enter your real birthday in the Birthday field
> 5. Save your changes